# Javascript does not work from HTML page loaded through Pistache

Tags: javascript, c++, css, rest

I am working with a C++ library called Pistache to create a restful API. I have setup a route that I am using to serve a webpage from my app but when it loads I press a button that calls a javascript function I get a function not defined error. When I load this webpage by clicking on it in my directory the Javascript works fine.

I am serving the webpage like this.

First adding the route

`Routes::Get(router, "/getCalibrationPage", Routes::bind(&CalibrationHandler::GetCalibrationPage, this));`

Then the function that gets called from this route

```
{
std::string txt;
std::ifstream file("index.html");

if (file.is_open())
{
    std::string tempTxt;
    while (file.good())
    {
        getline(file, tempTxt);
        txt += tempTxt;
    }
}
file.close();

response.send(Http::Code::Ok, txt, MIME(Text, Html));

}
```

Comment: sure, there you go. Do you have any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: Have you looked into the console of the developer tools of your browser (Press F12 in forefox or chrome)? At first you should check if the console tab shows any error and if the network tab shows any failures in the network requests.

Comment: Yes I have looked at the web console and there are no errors until I press one of the buttons that should be calling a javascript function. Then I get the function undefined error